# Solve the PDE $(x-y)p+(x+y)q=2xz$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Using multipliers, $1,1,-\frac{1}{z}$, we get $x+y-\log z=c_1$.

How do I get the second equation from Lagrange's auxiliary equation? $$\frac{dx}{x-y} = \frac{dy}{x+y} = \frac{dz}{2xz}$$ I think since the first two expressions only have $x$ and $y$ so they should be integrable. But it's still not so obvious for me. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(x-y)z_x+(x+y)z_y=2xz$$
$$\frac{dx}{x-y} = \frac{dy}{x+y} = \frac{dz}{2xz}\quad\text{OK}$$
I agree with your first characteristic equation : $x+y-\log z=C_1$ , or on an equivalent form with $c_1=e^{-C_1}$ :
$$z\,e^{-(x+y)}=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{x-y} = \frac{dy}{x+y}$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x+y}{x-y} $ . This is an homogeneous ODE easy to solve. Hint : Let $y(x)=x\:u(x)$ . One get :

$$\frac12\ln(x^2+y^2)-\tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE from the implicit form $c_1=F(c_2)$ is :
$$z(x,y)=e^{x+y}F\left(\frac12\ln(x^2+y^2)-\tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x}) \right)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function (to be determined according to some boundary condition).

Comment: Sorry, I am still not able to get the solution to ODE from the hint. Could you elaborate more.

Comment: $$y'=u+xu'=\frac{1+u}{1-u}$$ $$\frac{1-u}{1+u^2}u'=\frac{1}{x}$$ and integrate.